# riverbed wan optimizer does not receive traffic

Tags: switch, wan-optimizer, linux, riverbed

I have 2 Riverbed WAN optimizers and a WAN simulator. I connected 2 WAN ports of the 2 Riverbeds to the WAN simulator, connected 2 LAN ports along with 2 servers on a switch, and configured 2 subnets for the server and Riverbed –– But the Riverbed does not receive traffic from my servers.

Why? Is there something special I need to do for the Riverbed?

The topology is like so:

[image]

Comment: sorry, the image is a link, because I cannot add images now.

Comment: what do you have as the default gateways for the servers? you need to tell them when trying to reach the other server, to go to the riverbed first, and not the router. If they go to the router as their gateway for the other server, the router will just route between the directly connected networks.

Comment: What is the default gateway for your servers? Are you sure the traffic being routed between both servers is crossing the Steelhead appliances?

Comment: although the name is router platform, it is actually a L2 switch, so it does not have ip addresses, and the wan simulator between the 2 riverbed also does not have ip addresses.

Comment: Just to add, the Riverbed is totally transparent to any device using it when it is InPath. No need to change any routes or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the servers can ping each other:

- You need to check that the Optimization Service is enabled globally and for your inpath interface otherwise the Riverbed will not interact with network traffic at all.
- As soon as Optimization is enabled you can check under "Reports / Connected Appliances" if the Riverbeds can see each other.

Comment: Hi, I enabled the in-path interfaces, but there is no information in the connected appliances. how should I configure the ip address for the inpath interfaces?

Comment: please see the screenshot of the configuration:  http://i.imgur.com/1ByeRRS.png and http://i.imgur.com/WNobUNS.png

Comment: Your InPath interface has no default route and this will be the reason it is not working. The InPath-Interface of both Riverbeds need to be able to communicate with each other since they create a communication between each other.

Comment: if I understand correctly, the 2 riverbed need to configured into 1 subnet, so they can communicate, but what about the 2 server? does the server need to talk to riverbed?

Comment: current configuration is:

Comment: current configuration is: server 1(192.168.0.3) <==> riverbed1(192.168.0.2) <==>wan<==>riverbed2(192.168.1.2) <==> server2(192.168.1.3), because the 2 servers are connected to the same switch, so they cannot be in same subnet, otherwise they will talk directly not via riverbed, so in such condition, could you tell how can I confiugre ip addresses?

Comment: 1) The Servers need to be able to ping each other. 2) The Servers need to be able to ping the InPath interfaces of the Riverbeds 3) The InPath interfaces of the Riverbeds need to be able to ping each other. The Riverbed is totally transparent to the communication. Since it is InPath between each Subnet and the WAN it will see the SYN packets the Servers exchange and will flag this packets for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I know in my environment the use of crossover cables is necessary for optimization between router and simulator in this case.

Comment: As far as I know, Riverbed does recommend using crossover cables to connect the Steelhead WAN interface to the router, and straight-through cables to connect the Steelhead LAN interface to the switch. This is not mandatory as in-path ports do support MDIX, but is recommended in order ensure connectivity if the Steelhead goes in to fail-to-wire mode and both the switch and router do not support MDIX.

Comment: Crossover cables do nothing more than align TX pairs to RX pairs on both sides for communication on like devices absent the MDIX capability, so optimization shouldn't be a concern here.